# ¿Cómo puedo ignorar un índice de un array dentro de un While luego de ya usarlo?

Tags: java, array, while

estoy buscando la forma de ignorar un índice de un vector luego de ya recorrerlo 2 veces; tengo un programa de encriptación mono-alfabética y para eso requiero cortar Arrays en cierto orden, el problema es que al poner 27 letras del alfabeto en una matriz del tamaño de una palabra clave por ejemplo "CLAVE" la matriz queda así:

0. YZ
1. STUWX
2. ÑOPQR
3. IJKMN
4. BDFGH
5. CLAVE

entonces **las primeras dos letras salen de una matriz normal**, necesito sacar en vertical los caracteres **EJ:(YSÑIBC)** de toda la matriz, pero al llegar al espacio 2 del vector [0] explota por que estoy usando **.substring()** y no puede cortar el vació obviamente; mi idea es indicarle a mi While *que primero comienze a guardar desde el índice 0 para adelante y cuando ya no exista "el que cortar en el vector[0]" que comience con el vector[1] hacia adelante ignorando el 0 por completo.*

```
    int puntero = 0;
    int punta   = 0;
    
    while(punta < tamaño) {
        
        while(puntero < finalArray.length){ 

            finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[puntero]).substring(punta,punta+1);

            //El 2 dentro del If indica cuantas letras sobra para luego de guardarlas ignorar el vector[0]
            if(punta < 2){
                //
                //CUANDO SE CUMPLE LA CONDICIÓN COMIENZA A IGNORAR AL 0 HASTA TERMINAR LOS DOS WHILES
                //
            }else{}
        }
        punta++;
        puntero = 0;
    }
    
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("FINAL: " + finalStr + " " + finalStr.length());
```

***ACÁ DEJARÉ UNA FORMA MÁS VISUAL DE VER LO QUE QUIERO HACER: (La matriz es más corta es solo para el ejemplo)***

```
    String finalStr = "";
    
    finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[0]).substring(0,1);
    finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[1]).substring(0,1);
    finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[2]).substring(0,1);
    
    finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[0]).substring(1,2);
    finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[1]).substring(1,2);
    finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[2]).substring(1,2);

    
  //finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[0]).substring(1,2); <-- LO DEBERÍA IGNORA POR INEXISTENCIA DE CARACTERES
    finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[1]).substring(2,3);
    finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[2]).substring(2,3);


  //finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[0]).substring(1,2); <-- X LO DEBERÍA IGNORA POR INEXISTENCIA DE CARACTERES
    finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[1]).substring(3,4);
    finalStr = finalStr + String.valueOf(finalArray[2]).substring(3,4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Divide y venceras*

Si en el indice 0 vas a obtener una dimensión distinta a las otras podrías trabajar primero con ella y luego  con el resto

```
  int i=0;
    int j=0;
//Concatenar la primera letra de todos los indices en el array
//Concatenera la segunda letra de todos los indices en el array
      while(i<finalArray[0].length()){//0-2
        while(j<finalArray.length){
           finalStr = finalStr +finalArray[j].substring(i,i+1);//0-1 1-2
           j++;
         }
          j=0;
          i++;
       }
       j++;//ignoramos el primer indice ya trabajado
    //Concatenamos la 3era letra de todos los indices y asi en adelante
      while(i<palabra.length()){//2-5
        while(j<finalArray.length){
           finalStr = finalStr +finalArray[j].substring(i,i+1);
           j++;
         }
          j=1;
          i++;
       
       }
```

[Ejecución](https://www.codiva.io/p/919f8742-d9fa-4a1e-96d8-cefde44195a5)
salida

```
YSÑIBCZTOJDLUPKFAWQMGVXRNHE
```